# Existence of $\lambda$-transitive linear orders for $\lambda \geq \aleph_0$

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, linear-orders

A linear order $(L, <)$ is $\lambda$-transitive iff any order-preserving bijection between sets of size $\lambda$ can be extended to an order automorphism of $L$.

For $\lambda < \aleph_0$, $2$-transitive orders can be found as the reduct of an ordered field and $2$-transitive implies $k$-transitive for all $k < \aleph_0$.  I'm curious about what happens when $\lambda$ is infinite.  In particular, do $\lambda$-transitive linear orders (or something like them) exist?

Some additional restriction seems necessary: different order types or map between a sequence with a lub and one without would cause problems.  If the definition requires the sets to be inf and sup closed, does this help?

Comment: Any first-order structure has a strongly $\lambda^+$-homogeneous elementary extension, and any strongly $\lambda^+$-homogeneous dense linear order is $\lambda$-transitive in your terminology.

Comment: (Conversely, note that a 2-transitive order with at least 3 elements has to be dense.)

Comment: What is an "increasing set"?

Comment: That, too. In the comment above, I interpreted “increasing bijection between increasing sets” as “order-preserving bijection between sets”.

Comment: I did mean order-preserving bijection; this has been changed.

@EmilJeřábek wouldn't a strongly homogeneous model require that the maps be elementary, while an order-preserving bijection would just preserve quantifier-free formulas?

Comment: Yes, which is exactly the reason why all $\lambda$-transitive orders must be dense (IOW, have quantifier elimination). A non-elementary map can never be extended into an automorphism, so you need to ensure elementarity in one way or another.

Comment: That is, the following are equivalent for any structure $M$: (1) every partial self-embedding of size $\le\lambda$ extends to an automorphism; (2a) $M$ is strongly $\lambda^+$-homogeneous, and (2b) every partial self-embedding [of size $\le\lambda$, makes no difference] is elementary. If $M$ has quantifier elimination, (2b) holds automatically. For linear orders, (2b), quantifier elimination, and density are equivalent. If you insist that the $\lambda$-transitivity condition only applies to sets of size *exactly* $\lambda$, rather than at most $\lambda$, the only difference it will make ...

Comment: ... is that all orders of size $<\lambda$ are vacuously $\lambda$-transitive.